# How do Express views get rendered and sent to the user if they're not in the public directory?

Tags: node.js, security, express

I've been watching a few development videos that say only give users access to what's in your public directory so you're not revealing your source code to the world.

So I get it, js, css, and images should all go in a public directory because how else would a user receive a webpage when they visit your site?

But when I create an app with Express, our views, which contain what a user will see when they visit our site's index, are in a views directory rather than a public directory. I'm assuming Express renders the view and creates a public file that the user can read?

How exactly can a user receive an HTML file if it's not present within a public directory? And as an aside, what permissions should my Express app's directories and files have if I'm running it on my own VPS?

Answer (score 0):

When a view is rendered, it does not create a file, it sends the rendered output directly back to the client in the HTTP response. This is how dynamic content works.

Static content (what is in your "public" directory) on the other hand is transferred as-is because no transformation is needed in those cases.